# Replicate a view where the table doesn't exist 

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, replication, dynamics-crm

I am replicating from MS SQL Server 2005 to a MS SQL Server 2008 (Microsoft CRM Dynamics database).

There are a number of views in the source db which no longer have their underlying tables. I have no idea why this is or how it occured.

The issue is that the subscriber can't create these views so the subscription keeps failing part way through.

I have been working through view by view trying to find all the dependencies. Each time I change the Articles to be published, I need to create a new snapshot which puts huge load on the server and causes a problem for our users.

1. Is there any way to transfer the view structure to the other server and then just replicate the data/tables?
2. Is there a way to ensure the rest of the subscription continues after it finds a failure point?
3. Is there a way to update the snapshot without having it repeat the bits that were already successful?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: Found an answer to question 3:
http://www.replicationanswers.com/TransactionalOptimisation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to create the missing tables first on the old server, and then just setup/do a normal replication?

Seems you are going to need to create them one way or the other....might as well make your life easier by doing it first. Views will be of no use without the underlying table anyway.